# Removing and Replacing decimals in an IP address (from string to integer and vice versa)

Tags: php

Basically, I need to pass through an IP address as a parameter in a website that I'm linking to, however I'm not sure that a string broken with "." decimals can be accepted as a value (I think only a-z and 0-9 can be passed), so it would need to be an integer.

The IP address will also be posted back to me after the other server has validated a few things, and I'll need to reconvert it into a full string IP address.

Is there any easy way to remove the decimal points from an IP address, and then replace them again?

Answer (score 3):

What about using [**`ip2long()`**](http://www.php.net/ip2long) and [**`long2ip()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.long2ip.php) ?

Comment: `$ip_addr = "192.168.100.25";
$s32int = ip2long($ip_addr);
$us32str = sprintf("%u",$s32int);            
printf("%s ,%d, %s, %s", $ip_addr, $s32int, $us32str, 
         long2ip(-(4294967296-$us32str)));`

Good idea, I didn't know the function existed. Just taking a look at the PHP.net documentation, I found someone who pretty much wanted to do exactly what I want to. I understand everything in the code above, except for why the fourth print value is given as `long2ip(-(4294967296-$us32str))` as oppose to merely `(-($us32str))` or `($s32str)`?